# Why are "random" numbers plugged from memory often extremely large?

Tags: memory, floating-point, double, random-access

Sometimes during development of e.g. C code, you may accidentally index an array beyond its last element, resulting in a read of an essentially "random" chunk of memory. I work a lot with arrays of `double`s and have noticed that when this happens, the `double` produced from the "random" memory is often very large, as in larger than `1e+300`. I wonder why this is.

If the 64 bits used for interpreting the `double` were truly random, I would expect the exponent of the `double` to be uniformly distributed from `0` to `308` (ignoring the sign of the exponent), due to the way floating point numbers are laid out in memory using scientific (exponential) notation. Of course the values of the randomly selected bits in memory are not themselves randomly distributed, but corresponds to some meaningful state for whatever process set these values.

To investigate this effect I wrote the following Python 3 script, which plots the distribution of both truly randomly generated `double`s and `double`s taken from "random" but unused memory:

```py
import random, struct
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10000

def random_floats(N=1):
    return np.array(struct.unpack('d'*N, bytes(random.randrange(256) for _ in range(8*N))))

def exp_hist(a, label=None):
    a = a[~np.isnan(a)]
    a = a[~np.isinf(a)]
    a = a[a != 0]
    if len(a) == 0:
        print('Zeros only!')
        return
    a = np.abs(np.log10(np.abs(a)))
    plt.hist(a, range=(0, 350), density=True, alpha=0.8, label=label)

# Floats generated from uniformly random bits
a = random_floats(N)
exp_hist(a, 'random')

# Floats generated from memory content
a = np.empty(N)
exp_hist(a, 'memory')

plt.xlabel('exponent')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

A typical result of running this script is shown below:

[image]

The exponents of the truly randomly generated `double`s are indeed uniformly distributed.

The exponents of the `double`s interpreted from memory content are either very small or very large. In fact, much of unused memory is zeroed out, leading to a lot of `0` values, which makes sense. However, just as I so often experience from out-of-bounce memory access, a lot of values near `1e+300` show up as well.

I would like an explanation of this large amount of extremely large `double`s.

#### Note on running the script

If you would like to try out the script yourself, be aware that you may have to run it several times for anything interesting to show up. It may happen that every single number read from memory content will be `0`, in which case it will tell you so. If this happens repeatedly, try lowering `N` (the number of `double`s used).

Comment: By “randomly,” you actually mean uniformly. A uniform (random) distribution is one in which every element has an equal probability of occurring (or, for continuous distributions, every interval has a probability of occurring proportional to the size of the interval). Distributions in which different elements have different probabilities are still random, just not uniform.

Comment: Memory layouts tend to cluster things in the address space around 0, 0x7fff…, 0x8000…, and 0xffff…. So the presence of pointers with values around 0x7ff… would explain large `double` values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The question specifically uses the term *uniformly* random, when this is the intended meaning. Why would memory layouts tend to cluster things around those values?

Comment: “If … were truly random,” should be “truly random with uniform distribution”. “ truly randomly generated” should be “truly randomly generated with uniform distribution”.

Comment: Memory layouts are clustered around those values because long ago people sat around thinking “Where should I put stuff?” Some of them started at 0, then put the next thing at 1, then 2, and so on, or at 4, 8, 12, or whatever multiples they needed. Then somebody said okay, we’ve put our code and some of our data there. Hey, I have got an idea, let’s make a stack. Where should we put it? Since the “bottom” (0) was already used, maybe they started at the top of their address space (perhaps 0xffff back then) and work downward.

Comment: On another occasion, somebody decided it would be useful to partition the address space into an area for the user to arrange stuff in and an area for the operating system to arrange stuff in, and they decided everything starting with bit 0 is for the user and everything starting with bit 1 is for the operating system. Then the user puts stuff at 0 and up (maybe skipping the first page to reserve it for null pointer traps) and puts their stack at 0x7ffff… and down, and the operating system similarly puts some stuff at 0x8000… and up and other stuff at 0xffff… and down.

Comment: Basically, the memory space gets chopped up by humans dividing it up this way and that.

Comment: Could you explain the line `a = np.abs(np.log10(np.abs(a)))`? Why take the absolute value of the log?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan The first `abs()` is to make the number positive, as `log10()` fails on negatives. The result of `log10()` is then the exponent of the original number, which may be anything from about `-323` to `308` (i.e. the range of `double`s is about `1e-323` to `1e+308`, disregarding the sign). I don't care about the sign of the exponent, only that it's far from `1`, so I take another `abs()`.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan The sign of the exponent is determined from a single bit and as so is of little interest, except of course if it turned out that one sign appears much more often than the other. I disregard NaNs and infs basically just so that the remaining data may be plotted.

Comment: I think you are underestimating the asymmetry between all-exponent-bits-zero and all-exponent-bits-one.

Comment: In particular, it is probable that what you are interpreting as "very large" are almost all really very small. The decision to drop the exponent sign makes it impossible to be certain from the program output.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different things you might find in memory, but a surprising number of them map to very big or very small floating point numbers, infinities, or NaNs. In what follows, "FP" means IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point.

First, because they have already been discussed in comments on the question, consider addresses. A 64 bit address usually has all the exponent bits zero (low end of memory), or all the exponent bits high (high end of memory, often stack addresses). If all the exponent bits are high, it is an infinity or NaN, which the program seems to ignore. If all the exponent bits are zero, it is a sub-normal number or zero. Sub-normal numbers are all less than 2.3E-308, counted as exponent 308.

Now consider 32 bit integers, another very common form of data. Negative 32-bit twos complement integers that map to finite FP are -1048577 or less. Numbers like -42 or -1 map to NaNs, ignored by the program. Similarly, moderate value positive integers have all the exponent bits zero and so map to sub-normal numbers, mapped to the large exponent end of the histogram. Even the small normal numbers correspond to surprisingly large integers. For example, the leading 32 bits of 1e-300 have integer value 
27,618,847.

For both pointers and integers, there is a strong bias towards all the exponent bits having the same value, either all zero or all one. All one is a NaN or infinity, not counted by the program. All zero is subnormal, counted as very large exponent.